# Git push everything to new origin

Tags: git, branch, commit

I deleted my previous git origin, and created a new one. I did git add . and git commit. But it will update changes, how do i push everything into the new origin

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
git remote add origin <address>
git push origin <branchname>
```

Comment: You probably also want to add `--track master` to that first command, assuming you intend to push to/pull from the new origin. So: `git remote add --track master origin <address>`

Comment: This just pushes the specified branch. no other branches, no tags. Downvoted

Answer (score 88):

(works with git 1.8.4)

If you want to **push all branches** at once:

```
git push <URL> --all
```

To **push all the tags**:

```
git push <URL> --tags
```

Comment: When I do this in git 1.8.4, it only pushes the branches.  To push the tags, I need to do: git push <URL> --tags

Answer (score 1):

Hmmmm I just did this. I am not sure if you did exactly the same but I had a different method.

I setup a bare repo on "newserver" (using ssh). Had the full clone of the repo on my laptop.

I then did:

```
git remote set-url origin "newservers url"
git push origin master
```

Comment: and it pushes only master branch.

Answer (score -2):

git push new_remote_name branch_name

Comment: Where do you define `new_remote_name`?

Comment: `git remote add new_remote_name <address>`
Refer to the accepted answer.