# Cloning a repo from someone else's Github and pushing it to a repo on my Github

Tags: git, github

I cloned the repo at https://github.com/railstutorial/sample_app_rails_4 and made a lot of changes to it (I used it as a starting point for my own app), and now I would like to push the changed app to a repo on my own github account.

How can I change what github repo it is linked to?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to change a remote repository URI using Git?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2432764/how-to-change-a-remote-repository-uri-using-git)

Comment: also of possible interest https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33817118/github-how-to-fork-after-cloning

Answer (score 181, accepted):

As Deefour says, your situation isn't much unlike the one in [Change the URI (URL) for a remote Git repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2432764/how-to-change-a-remote-repository-uri-using-git). When you `clone` a repository, it is added as a `remote` of yours, under the name `origin`. What you need to do now (as you're not using the old source anymore) is change `origin`'s URL:

```
$ git remote set-url origin http://github.com/YOU/YOUR_REPO
```

If the original repository would update often and you want to get those updates from time to time, then instead of editing `origin` it would be best to add a new `remote`:

```
$ git remote add personal http://github.com/YOU/YOUR_REPO
```

Or maybe even call the old one `upstream`:

```
$ git remote rename origin upstream
$ git remote add origin http://github.com/YOU/YOUR_REPO
```

Then, whenever you want to get changes from `upstream`, you can do:

```
$ git fetch upstream
```

As this the source is a sample repository (seems to be kind of a template to start off), I don't think there's a need to keep it nor fork it at all - I'll go with the first alternative here.

Comment: I did this originally (I tried both options at different times), but I kept getting an error saying I did not have access (I don't know the exact message b/c I'm not at my computer right now, but I can add it later). Thanks

Comment: @jackerman09: whenever you can, please provide the error message so we can work it out.

Comment: here's the error message I'm getting when I run git push to an existing repo: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.

Comment: @jackerman09: [Verify the public key is attached to your GitHub account](https://help.github.com/articles/error-permission-denied-publickey#verify-the-public-key-is-attached-to-your-github-account) (or read the hole page, if that doesn't help). Or you can try [using HTTPS authentication](https://help.github.com/articles/changing-a-remote-s-url) instead.

Comment: thanks for the help! The answer was that I had no ssh key on the computer I was using. Here are the sites I used to figure it all out: 1) https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys AND 2) https://help.github.com/articles/error-permission-denied-publickey   Thanks again!

Comment: I'm late to the party. I've done all the steps above. The original repo is indeed updated very often, and I'm out of sync because I don't want to do a PULL. The original repo is named "upstream" now. I've added my own repo that I want to PUSH to as origin. The original branch is, say "version-13". My own branch is "main". I'm using "main". My GitHub repo is blank; no .gitignore, no README.md. Nothing. When I PUSH, I always get "error: src ref spec origin does not match any\n failed to push some refs to 'main'". Aiya... no idea how to get this PUSHed.

Answer (score 120):

**GitHub: `git clone` someone else's repository & `git push` to your own repository**

I'm going to refer to ***someone else's*** repository as the ***other repository***.

---

1. **Create a new repository at [github.com](https://github.com).** (this is *your repository*)

- Give it the same name as the *other repository*.
- Don't initialize it with a README, .gitignore, or license.

2. **Clone the *other repository* to your local machine.** (if you haven't done so already)

- `git clone https://github.com/other-account/other-repository.git`

3. **Rename the local repository's current '*origin*' to '*upstream*'.**

- `git remote rename origin upstream`

4. **Give the local repository an '*origin*' that points to *your repository*.**

- `git remote add origin https://github.com/your-account/your-repository.git`

5. **Push the local repository to *your repository* on github.**

- `git push origin main`

---

**Now '*origin*' points to *your repository* & '*upstream*' points to the *other repository*.**

- Create a new branch for your changes with `git checkout -b my-feature-branch`.
- You can `git commit` as usual to *your repository*.
- Use `git pull upstream main` to pull changes from the *other repository* to your main branch.

Comment: Can you include how (in addition to the above) you can make a pull request  to "the other repository" ? This would make it a very helpful mini tutorial

Comment: @TanyaGupta GitHub has a great tutorial page on [Creating a pull request from a fork](https://help.github.com/articles/creating-a-pull-request-from-a-fork/).

Comment: Excellent explonation, brief, and simple

Comment: Nice explanation but when trying to `git push origin master` I get: `...
Compressing objects: 100% (1093/1093), done.
Writing objects: 100% (4185/4185), 504.89 KiB | 126.22 MiB/s, done.
Total 4185 (delta 3049), reused 4185 (delta 3049)
remote: Resolving deltas: 100% (3049/3049), done.
remote: pre-receive.sh: execution exceeded 5s timeout
To https://github.com/your-account/your-repository.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/your-account/your-repository.git'`

Comment: ! [rejected]        master -> master (fetch first)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/your-account/your-repo.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the remote contains work that you do
hint: not have locally. This is usually caused by another repository pushing
hint: to the same ref. You may want to first integrate the remote changes
hint: (e.g., 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.

Comment: To avoid the remote-rejected silliness, you may need to change step 5 to use `git@github` instead of https.

Answer (score 22):

### Delete git and re-init.

Your purpose is probably to put this repo on yours and make it yours.

#### The idea is to delete the `.git/` and re-initialize.

1. Go to your cloned repo folder

```bash
rm -rf .git
```

2. Re-initialize it and then add your remote and do your first push.

```bash
git init
git add .
git commit -m "your commit message"
git remote add origin <address>
git push origin main
```

Comment: Do you even have to remove the `.git` directory first? Won't `git init` wipe it out anyway?

Comment: @MikeWise: No, git init will never destroy any data if a repo already exists there, but can alter a few settings via the command-line args you pass, I think.

Comment: By removing git, and reinit we will lost the commit history and multiple branches of the repository. I will not recommend it to anyone.

Answer (score 9):

I think that the "most polite way" to do so would be:

1. Fork the original repo on your GitHub account
2. Checkout a new branch for your changes `git checkout -b <your_branch_name>` (in case you didn't do that before)
3. Add a new remote for your local repository: `git remote add github <your_repository_ssh_url>`
4. Push your beautiful new branch to your github repository: `git push github <your_branch_name>`

In this way you will have a repo forked to the original one, with your changes commited in a separate branch. This way will be easier  in case you want to submit a pull request to the original repo.

Comment: Took me a minute to note that `github` in these instructions is the bit usually referred to as `origin`. Otherwise, straightforward and simple.

Answer (score 8):

You can do this by creating a new remote from your local repository (via commandline).

```
git remote add <name> <url>
```

then you can call:

```
git push <name> <repo_name>
```

To replace the default "origin" remote that is set up you can run the following:

```
git remote rm origin
git remote add origin <url>
```

Comment: I did this originally, but I kept getting an error saying I did not have access (I don't know the exact message b/c I'm not at my computer right now, but I can add it later). Thanks

Comment: You may have to create the repository on your remote account first, then take that url to configure the new remote.

Comment: This is what I had done (creating the repo directly at github.com first). I reinitialized the local repo (git init), removed the remote's (rm origin) and re-added origin. That all worked, but when I tried to push to the repo I got the 'Fatal Error' saying 'Access Denied'

Comment: try running "git config --list" and make sure you are using the right user and remotes.

Comment: I ran git config --list and the username, email and remote are correct. How can I confirm that my password is stored correctly? Can I re-enter the password?

Comment: are you sure you don't have an ssh key set up?  On invalid password (if it is using a password), it should prompt for the password.

Comment: thanks for following up. I got this working, it turns out I did not have an SSH key setup. Thanks again for the help

Answer (score 1):

Taken from  [Git push everything to new origin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7630574/git-push-everything-to-new-origin)

basically you have to associate a new repo to your folder

```
git remote add origin <address>
git push origin <branchname>
```

Comment: `origin` already exists - you have to `rm`, `rename` or `set-url` it.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar situation, but in my case what I just needed to do was, as suggested, but with **https**, like this:

`$ git remote set-url origin https://github.com/YOU/YOUR_REPO`

Answer (score 1):

After cloning, copy the files from their folder  into a new one and start afresh with
git init,

I had a similar problem like that I had to change the folder directory before I could stage the changes to my repo.

or you can remove current repository origin by the command
git remote remove origin.

Answer (score 0):

To save messing, I usually do this

1. Clone it to a temp directory
2. Create a new git repo with a README
3. Clone that repo to my machine
4. Delete all the git files from the original
5. Copy all files to my repo
6. Push it

Carry on as normal there and you can't be tripped up by issues with git. I do this fairly often. Certainly not as 'pure' as the other answers, but trauma free and removes any potential problems you may have.

Answer (score 0):

Using vscode, these other solutions did not quite work for me,

Instead, I ran

> git init

This will make it so that the 'new branch' button makes a completely new repository when you go to commit. I could not figure out how to commit into an already uninitialize repository.

edit : Since i was following a tutorial, i'm not very experienced with git, The flags were the culprit [Remote rejected (shallow update not allowed) after changing Git remote URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28983842/remote-rejected-shallow-update-not-allowed-after-changing-git-remote-url)

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me as of December 2022. Straight forward

1. I cloned the repo and then create a new repo on GitHub with a new name and no file
2. I duplicated the folder and renamed it
3. In the terminal (within the folder), `rm -rf .git` to del all existing git files
4. I `git init` to initialize
5. I `git add -- . ': path'` where the path was a directory with large weights I did not want to commit. It causes an error if you add all
6. `git commit -m "message"`
7. `git remote add origin https://github.com/xxx/xxxx.git` to newly created repo
8. `git branch -M main`
9. `git push -u origin main`

Answer (score 0):

Simply:

```
git remote add origin https://github.com/your-username/name-of-repo.git
git branch -M main
git push -u origin main
```

UPDATE:
Or `master` instead of `main` depends on the name of your master branch.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the steps mentioned in @Derek Soike's answer, you can change the default configured remote in order to use push and pull without specifying origin: (for branch named main)

1. check what is the default remote:

```
git config branch.main.remote
```

expected output for our case: upstream

2. set the default remote to origin:

```
git config branch.main.remote origin
```

Answer (score -1):

I have the same problem. If you just want the files in the repo and push them just as if they were normal files, you can..

1. Download zip
2. Open terminal (or cmd on windows)
3. Delete the .github and .gitigore files (rm -r .github)(rm .gitigore)
4. Copy and paste the directory into your project 
   Github won't know that these are from another repo since the config files are gone.

It's doesn't have the hassle of messing too much with the command line and running into problems.