# Remote rejected (shallow update not allowed) after changing Git remote URL

Tags: git

I have a project under Git version control that I worked on both a server and my local computer. I originally had the remote origin set as my local computer but I would now like to change that to BitBucket.

On the server I used the command

```
git remote set-url origin bitbucket_address
```

But now when I try to push my project I get the error

```
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (shallow update not allowed)
```

What is causing this and how do I fix it?

Comment: How did you clone your local version? `git clone --depth`?

Comment: It was a while ago and I can't remember. Is there a way to find out?

Comment: There should be a file named `shallow` in you `.git` folder.

Comment: Yes, I can see a `shallow` file.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/50996201 for a solution that just discards (or rewrites) the missing history

Comment: ideally enable `receive.shallowUpdate` on the git server

Answer (score 487, accepted):

As it seems you have used `git clone --depth <number>` to clone your local version. This results in a *shallow clone*. One limitation of such a clone is that you can't push from it into a **new** repository.

You now have two options:

1. if you don't care about your missing history, take a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29748197/how-to-clone-seed-kick-start-project-without-the-whole-history)
2. if you want to keep your full history, then continue reading:

So, you want to keep your history, eh? This means that you have to *unshallow* your repository. If you already removed or replaced your old remote then you'll need to add it again:

```
git remote add old <path-to-old-remote>
```

After that we use `git fetch` to fetch the remaining history from the old remote (as suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17937889/2274224)).

```
git fetch --unshallow old
```

And now you should be able to push into your new remote repository.

---

**Note**: After *unshallowing* your clone you can remove the old remote.

Comment: what if i cloned a kick-start project and i don't want/need the whole history? is there a way to avoid it?

Comment: @itamar This seems to be a good example for a perfectly valid new question. You could link to this question for reference.

Comment: Asked as new question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29748197/how-to-clone-seed-kick-start-project-without-the-whole-history

Comment: Note that `git fetch --unshallow` can take a refspec to only unshallow a certain branch rather than the whole repo. E.g.: `git fetch --unshallow origin refs/heads/mydeepbranch:refs/remotes/origin/mydeepbranch`

Comment: If you are pushing to a repo that is a bit behind whatever repo you cloned from, not creating an all-new repo, it is enough that your local reference is deep enough to contain the remote reference. So if your `origin/master` was 20 commits ahead of your `oldrepo/master` when you `clone --depth 1`'ed it, and you have made 17 local commits since, it is enough for you to do `git fetch --depth 37 origin refs/heads/master:refs/remotes/origin/master` (apologies for any off-by-one error), and then you can do `git push oldrepo master` without incident (may require git 1.9.0 or newer).

Comment: @itamar delete /.git/ (& reference in package.json) and git init

Comment: Usually you won't need to add old rep, so just use the git fetch command

Answer (score 55):

In case your repo is `origin`, and the original repo is `upstream`:

```
git fetch --unshallow upstream
```

Comment: this works for me, and quite easy then the top voted answer.

Answer (score 29):

Another option if you want to keep the repo as is with the new commits you have added since the shallow, initial commit is this: **Amend this commit with an interactive rebase**.

- Start an interactive rebase including the first (root) commit with

  ```
  git rebase --interactive --root
  ```
- Change the `pick` of the initial commit(s) to `edit` and save & close the file.

  If you've cloned the repo with greater depth than 1, you may need to do the same for all of those commits. Or, alternatively, execute `fixup` for all of these during the interactive rebase.
- Convert this commit to a regular, unshallow commit with

  ```
  git commit --amend --no-edit
  ```

  This will also change the commit ID and add you as co-author to this initial commit.
- Don't forget to finish your rebase

  ```
  git rebase --continue
  ```

Comment: Thank you! Worked like a charm, when the original repository was deleted and you have only a shallow copy of it.

Comment: fatal: No rebase in progress?

Comment: error: src refspec main does not match any

Answer (score 17):

If you want to push the new repo as it is, you can try this:

- First remove the `old git folder` from your current repo,`sudo rm -rf .git`
- Then initialize the git again
  `git init`
- Then add the new remote repo
  `git remote add origin your-new-repo`
- Then Push it.

Comment: I found this a better solution, since it doesn't require a push to the old. Sometimes this could happen with boilerplates.

Comment: This is basically the answer from the [related question which you can find here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29748197/how-to-clone-seed-kick-start-project-without-the-whole-history).

Comment: @NachPD I'm not sure what you mean, when you say that the other solution requires "a push to the old". Do you mean a fetch instead of a push? Because it does not require a push.

Answer (score 4):

If fetching --unshallow doesn't work. There must be some problems with your branch. Fix it with the following command before pushing it.

```
git filter-branch -- --all
```

Do this only with --unshallow doesn't work since there's a [SAFETY](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-filter-branch#SAFETY) concern.

Comment: This will help you push a local repo with the history cut by `git clone file://<path> <dirname> --depth=<N>`. Such shallow clone will not be pushable, because the history will be only hidden by graft. The `filter-branch` will drop it.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this issue. but maybe you can not fixed it. the solution as follows.

1. get the shallow file from the git, like common/.git/shallow
2. push this file to the .git directory in git server.
3. push your branch to the git server.

In my company, I need the IT admin to add the file, and I have not permissions.

Answer (score 1):

In case of bitbucket pipeline

It might be due to limited depth of commit (default 50 commit)

You can increase limit

```
clone:
  depth: 500       # include the last five hundred commits
  
pipelines:
  default:
    - step:
        name: Cloning
        script:
          - echo "Clone all the things!"
```

> Note : Use **depth: full** for no limit

Answer (score 0):

Based on the most upvoted answer, I created an alias to automate things:

Add to your `.gitconfig`:

```
[alias]
    unshallow = !"git fetch --unshallow \"${1:-origin}\" # Unshallow from remote $1 (defaults to origin)"
```

Usage:

- `git unshallow`  # unshallow current branch based on the `origin` remote
- `git unshallow other-remote`  # unshallow current branch from remote `other-remote`

Answer (score 0):

For simply resolving this issue if you don't care about the remote existing changes then do it the following way.

1. Remove your local `.git` folder from your repository.
2. Type `git init`.
3. Add your remote again `git remote add origin <REMOTE_URL>`.
4. Set `main` branch by `git branch -M main`.
5. Push your changes then `git push --set-upstream origin main`.

Comment: fatal: Invalid branch name: 'HEAD'

Answer (score -1):

Just delete the `shallow` file in your /.git/shallow

Now it should work.

Comment: !git push -f https://{repo} main
fatal: unable to get credential storage lock: File exists
Counting objects: 347, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (245/245), done.
Writing objects: 100% (347/347), 56.28 MiB | 1.56 MiB/s, done.
Total 347 (delta 153), reused 250 (delta 99)
remote: Resolving deltas: 100% (153/153), done.
remote: fatal: did not receive expected object 2aaa07546a89ead5a106b6ed48beb3ce3a485c8a
error: unpack failed: index-pack failed
To https://github.com/
 ! [remote rejected] main -> main (failed)
error: failed to push some refs to

Comment: git fetch --unshallow https://github.com/  解决上述问题