# mean.io push to git repo

Tags: git, bitbucket, mean-stack

I created a project on mean stack (mean.io) using

```
mean init
```

This created a git repo which I want to push into my own private git repo on Bitbucket. I did:

```
git remote add origin git@bitbucket.org:my_login/reponame.git
git push -u origin --all
```

I'm getting the following error

```
! [remote rejected] master -> master (shallow update not allowed)
```

Any advice on how I can push my local repo into brand new remote repo on Bitbucket?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
git fetch --unshallow upstream
```

Then

```
git push -u origin --all
```

Comment: "git fetch --unshallow upstream" is what I needed but couldn't find in docs. Thank you!

Comment: this recipe helps also in case of the following error from bitbucket: ` ! [remote rejected] master -> master (missing necessary objects)` - thank you!

Answer (score 1):

On which branch do you want to push the local repo? Try to define every time the remote branch on which you want to push the local repo.

```
git push -u origin master --all
```

If it's not working then check this answer:

[Remote rejected (shallow update not allowed) after changing Git remote URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28983842/remote-rejected-shallow-update-not-allowed-after-changing-git-remote-url)

Comment: I got this error :
error: --all can't be combined with refspecs