# Errors trying to push to Heroku

Tags: git, heroku, heroku-toolbelt

Running into an issue with Heroku not accepting my builds. I'm getting this error: `! [remote rejected] 15ec80ba31f02e6d7aafc1cbca76a1be0b148207 -> master (shallow update not allowed)`

Everything is working on my local system, so is there something I'm not doing right with git?

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28983842/remote-rejected-shallow-update-not-allowed-after-changing-git-remote-url

Comment: @RetoAebersold didn't seem to help. I did a clean pull on my repo and pushed up a few changes and I'm getting the same error.

Comment: "I did a clean pull", what do you mean by this? What was the command you used? As it stands, this error only occurs when you try to push a *shallow clone* to a fresh remote.

Comment: @Zeeker . I did a fresh clone of my respository to my local machine and tried to push to Heroku. Same issue.

Comment: @m0ngr31 is there a `shallow` file in your `.git` folder?

Comment: @m0ngr31 did you find a solution to that problem?