# Shallow update not allowed (git > 1.9)

Tags: git

There are a lot of answers stating that git 1.9 removes limitations of shallow clones. Nevertheless, I'm using 2.6.1 and still having the following basic issue:

First, I create an empty repo somewhere:

```
cd /tmp
mkdir target
cd target
git init
```

Then, I shallow clone some repo and add the above repo as remote:

```
cd /tmp
git clone --depth 1 git@github.com:muennich/urxvt-perls.git
cd urxvt-perls
git remote add target /tmp/target
```

Finally, I push this repo to the remote:

```
git push target master
```

But then I get:

```
! [remote rejected] master -> master (shallow update not allowed)
error: failed to push some refs to '/tmp/target'
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: If you are interested in gitlab allowing this check https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/3033.

Comment: look at this [remote-rejected-shallow-update-not-allowed-after-changing-git-remote-url](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28985327/2206581)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm answering my own question.

I tried going the other way around and adding `urxvt-perls` as a remote for `target`, then fetching from there. This fails because of the same reason but led me closer to a solution. From the `git-fetch` man:

```
  --update-shallow
       By default when fetching from a shallow repository, git fetch
       refuses refs that require updating .git/shallow. This option
       updates .git/shallow and accept such refs.
```

Now, using this option allows the shallow fetch. So the previous question becomes: Is it possible to specify that `--update-shallow` behavior while pushing? Well, there is an option for that:

```
receive.shallowupdate
    If set to true, .git/shallow can be updated when new refs require
    new shallow roots. Otherwise those refs are rejected.
```

I'm still trying to set this in github and the likes, though.

Comment: So, Do you success in github or gitlab  now ?

Comment: No, I opened an issue in gitlab tracker some time ago but nobody really cares.

Comment: I'm also interested if Gerrit supports this

Comment: FWIW, the GitHub tracker is https://github.community/t/set-receive-shallowupdate-on-to-allow-pushing-from-shallow-clones/2424, and the GitLab tracker is https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-foss/-/issues/3033.

Answer (score 5):

```
git fetch --unshallow

git push target master -f
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `git merge --squash`.

If your remote is shallow and you want to merge from it, compress that [merge into a single commit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2427238/in-git-what-is-the-difference-between-merge-squash-and-rebase) without the need to copy a history of commits (which shallow refs hide).

Answer (score 0):

Well on Linux repo server...
this

```
git config --local --add receive.shallowUpdate true
```

resulted in this being added to the repo config file.

```
[receive]
    shallowUpdate = true
```

So maybe if you can add that to the repo config file.

Comment: If I use github Or Gitlab,How To add this config?