# Setting an option in a remote git repository

Tags: git, github, gitlab

I would like to set the `receive.shallowUpdate` option in a remote git repository (say a repo I created in gitlab or github) in order to be able to push a shallow clone (see [Shallow update not allowed (git > 1.9)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33085672/shallow-update-not-allowed-git-1-9) for context).

In other words, I need to modify the `.git/config` of a remote repository because it should be able to update from a push of a shallow clone. Is that even possible? Or, at least, is it possible in github? In gitlab?