# Is it possible to host a shallow git repository (e. g. GitLab, GitHub, …)?

Tags: git, github, gitlab, revision-history, shallow-clone

I want to make a git repository public, but without including all of the history in the public version. The git documentation seems to suggest [`git checkout --orphan`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout#Documentation/git-checkout.txt---orphanltnew-branchgt) as a potential solution to this:

> This can be useful when you want to publish the tree from a commit
> without exposing its full history. You might want to do this to
> publish an open source branch of a project whose current tree is
> "clean", but whose full history contains proprietary or otherwise
> encumbered bits of code.

However, I don’t want the histories of the two repositories to diverge (how could they be kept in sync?). I also don’t want to throw away the history entirely and only keep the new public version.

One (the?) way to prune old data from the history without rewriting it is to use a [shallow clone](https://git-scm.com/docs/shallow). However, it seems like I can’t really push a shallow repository to hosting services like GitLab or GitHub – see e. g. these existing questions:

- [Remote rejected (shallow update not allowed) after changing Git remote URL](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28983842)
- [Shallow update not allowed (git > 1.9)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33085672)
- [Setting an option in a remote git repository](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33087119)
- [How to push a shallow clone to a new repo?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50992188)
- [Push git to remote (Github) only one last commit, without history?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66832428)

Is there no way to make a public repository that starts with the same commit as an existing, private repository? It seems like a common problem!

---

*Update to clarify questions from the comments:* There seems to be some confusion about what the setup looks like. I tried not to be too specific in order to not restrict options for solutions, but perhaps that wasn’t helpful.

**Current situation:** There is a single private git repository whose history contains commits which cannot be made public (I don’t see why the specific reasons would matter, but imagine files with a proprietary license). The `HEAD` tree of the repository does not contain any such files and can be made public.

**Goal:** *Ideally*, there should continue to be only a single repository with the existing history, but the content of the “tainted” commits in the past should not be accessible in any publicly uploaded files. In other words, there would be two “copies” of the existing repository:

- “Private copy”: Same as before; not uploaded to any public web page.
- “Public copy”: The same as the private copy, including history, but the contents of all ancestors of a specific commit are omitted.

For the purposes of development, both repositories should be interchangeable: It should be possible to push commits from “private” to “public”, but also to pull from “public” to “private“ (e. g. pull requests). The only reason I mentioned “keeping them in sync” above was because the git documentation seems to imply that [`git checkout --orphan`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout#Documentation/git-checkout.txt---orphanltnew-branchgt) is a solution to this problem, but as far as I can tell it would require some additional mechanisms for synchronization because it would, by definition, introduce two separate divergent histories. As such, it doesn’t seem like a solution to the problem.

Comment: What is your purpose of providing an abbreviated public repository? If the history contains private info, could you instead clean up the history?

Comment: @Schwern This is not about “accidentally” having private info in the history, but legitimate parts that are however not supposed to be public (e. g. for legal reasons). “Cleaning up” the history in this case would just mean removing it, which I’m trying to avoid!

Comment: Are you looking to hide the commit info? Or are you looking to hide the content? Could you provide a concrete (but safe) example of what is public and what is private? I suspect there's a better way to solve this.

Comment: My suspicion is this could better be solved by moving hard coded private content into configuration files and plugins, while the main repo has only the safe and generic content.

Comment: @Schwern The commit info is fine, I just want to hide the content. And of course, there are usually ways to arrange things to split “private” content from the repository and keep it separate. But that’s no help when the history has already been written! I’m talking about an existing repository. If I go back and rewrite the entire history to split out the parts that shouldn’t become public, then by definition I lose the existing history (by changing it). Not to mention how much useless work this potentially creates!

Comment: Your Git history is not a museum; it has a purpose. If the rewritten history serves that purpose, you're fine. You can retain a private, read-only archive of the original repo for reference. "*Not to mention how much useless work this potentially creates!*" That work solves the problem for good. Or you can write and maintain a bespoke repo synching scheme for the rest of the life of the project, carefully deciding whether each change should be private or public.

Comment: @Schwern Yes, it serves a purpose, which is why I want to keep it! `git blame`, `git log -G`, and all the other ways you might look at the history don’t work when it only exists as a separate archive somewhere. *“That work solves the problem for good.”* Sure. But it seems very silly to invest this work if tools to solve the problem already exist.

Comment: Rewriting the history doesn't delete it. You'll still have the commit logs, except the private bits will be in another repo; it's normal to have a project broken up into multiple repos. I don't think this tool exists, lots of people have tried to solve your problem like this, but I'm keeping an eye on this question. If you're dead set against a rewrite, you could make the public repo with one commit per release like [Gitpan](https://github.com/gitpan). It's hard to say more without details of your project and the private/public split.

Comment: @Schwern I think we’ve gone full circle now, since this is just the question I asked in the first place. I’m not necessarily looking for suggestions of how to do things differently – if the answer to my question is “no, there’s no existing way of doing this”, I can come up with a number of (albeit less satisfactory) alternatives (e. g. those mentioned in my question text), including some that you mentioned. Shallow repositories seemed like a good solution to me, but it looks like they’re not allowed in most places for seemingly arbitrary reasons.

Comment: Keeping the branches synced after `git checkout --orphan` could be done by making use of `git reset --soft`. Every time you have reached a state in your private history which should be added to the public history do a `git reset --soft <public-branch>` and do a commit. This will however only work as long as nothing is ever committed directly to the public history, and is very manual :)

Comment: This question is missing some basic information. Is the intent to commit to both repos? How is the private/public split determined? Providing more information about the situation you find yourself in, and an example of how you would expect your solution to work, would help people answer.

Comment: @Schwern Not sure what you mean. *“Is the intent to commit to both repos?”* No, as stated in the question, I want to make the existing repo public without having to create a separate one, but without making the contents of some commits accessible. *“How is the private/public split determined?”* As stated in the question, a single commit is picked, and the contents of its ancestors should not be public. *“example of how you would expect your solution to work”* As stated in the question, I want it to work like a shallow clone, with the apparent problem that hosters don’t allow me to upload one.

Comment: @Socob I think there is a solution to your problem; it isn't a shallow clone, but I think something very similar could work. However, we need more information about your problem. 1) Sorry, I don't see where you say which you're committing to. You talk about the repos *diverging* which implies you're committing to both, could you make it clearer? 2) WRT how it would work, for example, when there are commits to the private repo, what happens to the public repo? Do all those commits appear in the public repo, or do you have to pick and choose?

Comment: @Schwern I added some text to the question. I hope that clarifies it!

Comment: "*It should be possible to push commits from “private” to “public”, but also to pull from “public” to “private“*" Do you need to be able to write to the private repo? Could everyone commit to the public one? That would make this much, much easier. Otherwise you're maintaining two long-running peer branches with no common ancestor; possible, but complicated.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand, you have...

1. A repo with private content in the past, but no longer.

   - Presumably no further private content will be added.
2. A desire to make the public bits public.
3. A desire to continue to commit to both simultaneously and keep them synced.

Your proposed solution is...

1. Provide a truncated public history at the first clean commit.
2. Find a tool to handle the synching.

## The Solution, As Required

This solution leaves you with a lot of complexity going forward.

### Conflicts. So many conflicts.

Let's say we find a solution to maintain and sync your orphaned public repo with your complete private repo. Regardless of the technical details; this involves maintaining two long running peer branches, merging them together periodically.

Because commits in the private repo might have non-public commits in their history, content from the private repo must be merged using a squash merge or cherry pick to avoid accidentally pulling in private history. This further complicates merging and further distorts the public history.

There's sure to be conflicts. Always and forever. In each direction. This is on top of normal conflicts you'd experience. No tool can handle conflicts for you, a human must be involved. This means every PR potentially comes with an extra level of merge complexity, and bugs, forever.

### Second class public citizens.

Because people on the public side can't see the private history, you'll have to maintain two separate projects with two separate sets of PRs. That's a bunch of overhead.

The people on the private side will have a full view of history and can see and work on all PRs, public and private.

Any changes from the private side have to come in as squash merges or cherry-picks; the people on the pubic side will always have a truncated and distorted history.

This puts anyone working on the public side at a disadvantage. Commits mirrored from the private side might reference commits and PRs they have no access to. The public side can't review, comment on, nor even see the private PRs (without a system of scrubbing out any private bits); changes will just appear in the public side, changes they had no say in and never saw before.

### Lava Flow Anti-Pattern

This is a variation on the [Lava Flow Anti-Pattern](http://antipatterns.com/lavaflow.htm). You have dead code from the past (the old private code); because it was not cleaned up, it continues to have negative consequences. None of the headaches and complexity I've described above is necessary for the current situation, it's all because of that old dead code.

For this reason I'm not going to get into a solution as specified. It's very complicated. You have to make an orphaned clone. Then when pulling changes from private those have to be squash merges, else you risk pulling in private history.

## Better Solution: Filter out the private parts.

Since the private content is all dead, and no further private content will be coming into the repo (if you need private content going forward, there are better options), but in the effort *now* to clean up your history and avoid the ongoing complexity outlined above.

There are many tools to help clean up history, primarily [git-filter-repo](https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo) and [BFG Repo Cleaner](https://rtyley.github.io/bfg-repo-cleaner/). These can remove files and directories based on their size, content, filename, directory, etc. They can search and replace content and commit messages. This might take some time, depends on how complex your history is, but it is a one time process.

When you're done, you'll have a complete history of the public parts of your repository. Any commits which contained only private content will either be gone or empty (your choice, probably gone). Any commits which contained mixed public and private parts will still exist, but only with the private parts. The commit IDs will be different, but this is no worse than your proposed solution; any critical commits can be referenced by tag.

This is now the repository.

You can keep the original repository as a private, read-only archive if you need to reference the private parts, but it's dead code so that should be infrequent and less frequent going forward. If you find you need to add private content later, these can use the "public" content as a dependency and add private content via configuration management and plugins.

And you're done. Your project does not have to worry about the public/private split going forward.

## Hybrid Solution: Private read-only, incremental cleanup.

If there's no more private content coming in, there's no need to commit to the private repo. Drop that requirement and leave the private repo as a read-only archive to be referenced as needed.

Now only the public repo and project is changing. Everyone works on the public project and public repo. Everyone is able see and comment on all future PRs. Since only one repo is changing, no complex repo syncing is necessary.

The disadvantage is "public" participants will never be able to see the full history. As the project moves forward there will be less and less need to reference the private repository and this scar will heal.

Meanwhile, you can incrementally work on cleaning up the history and grafting this clean onto the new repository.

Comment: I appreciate the effort, but this still seems like it misses the point. All three of your solutions involve “splitting” or creating two separate repositories (histories), which is exactly what I’m trying to avoid, for the reasons you mention. As I said earlier in a comment, *“if the answer to my question is ‘no, there’s no existing way of doing this’, I can come up with a number of (albeit less satisfactory) alternatives”*, the alternatives being solutions like the ones you’re presenting. So your answer seems to imply that the answer to the actual question is “no”? That’d be fair enough.

Comment: @Socob 1) The answer is "even if such a tool exists it'll still be a complex mess with divergent, mangled histories". 2) Technically yes there will be two histories, but one is an archive for referencing deleted code. Your need to access it would be increasingly infrequent (unless there's something else about the situation you haven't mentioned). If it really bugs you, write a little tool to search both histories. Functionally, it's one history going forward. Your proposed solution winds up with two projects, two actively divergent histories, and a lot safe history hidden from public users.

Comment: My “proposed solution” was a shallow git repository. Not sure what you’re talking about with “divergent histories” and “two projects”.

Comment: @Socob When I thought it through I found what look like fundamental problems with the idea of *working on both at the same time*. This is laid out in "The Solution, As Required". You need parallel private and public projects because private PRs will reference and display the private history which the public cannot see. Public contributors can never participate in these private PRs, changes will just show up in the public side. If the private side references commits from before the private/public break, the public side cannot know what they meant. Etc. It's a lot of work for everyone.

Comment: @Socob To be clear, these problems remain even if the shallow clone is made to work perfectly. The real problem remains (parts of the history cannot be seen by some), that problem still has to be dealt with. I've been asking how you imagine this will work in practice because the solution seems to create more problems.