# Is there a way to do a git push --mirror on a shallow clone?

Tags: git, git-push, repo

I am trying to do a shallow clone on a large repo and push it to a new destination.

I have done a shallow clone using:

git clone --depth 100 URL

but when I try to push it using:

git push --mirror URL

But I keep getting an error message - "error: failed to push some refs to".

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50992188/how-to-push-a-shallow-clone-to-a-new-repo

Answer (score 0):

This indicates that another user has pushed a commit to the branch you are pushing to, but that commit hasn't yet arrived on your laptop. This may occur if you haven't recently used "git pull" on a branch with a large number of contributors, like staging.
To fix this issue, run:

1. git pull origin ****your-branch
2. git push origin ****your-branch