# References to inaccessible Git LFS files hinder migrating the repository

Tags: git, git-lfs, git-lfs-migrate

I am working with the [Neptune 3 UI](https://codereview.qt-project.org/admin/repos/qt-apps/neptune3-ui,general) Qt repo. I want migrate the repository to my own remote. However, running `git push [myremote] [branch]` I get:

```
Unable to find source for object 3a03e4a5276156644ceb88328db71b548f1d1a688bd0f6fd08c286ed30caa126 (try running git lfs fetch --all)
error: failed to push some refs to '[remote-url]'
```

`git lfs fetch --all` throws the following error for a few hundred objects:

```
fetch: 1122 object(s) found, done.                                                                   
fetch: Fetching all references...
[09bd96ab35f610cdbdf84cc4b49a850c6af37d205c43c5e053a21ea6d37ccd6f] Object '09bd96ab35f610cdbdf84cc4b49a850c6af37d205c43c5e053a21ea6d37ccd6f' not found: [404] Object '09bd96ab35f610cdbdf84cc4b49a850c6af37d205c43c5e053a21ea6d37ccd6f' not found
...
```

After further analyzing the relevant commits with `git log -p -S`, it turns out that these LFS files have been replaced by newer ones, for instance:

```
commit 86b5980f8f8ad1ccb936b8207426ff54c262d872
Author: Bramastyo Harimukti Santoso <bramastyo.harimukti.santoso@pelagicore.com>
Date:   Mon Oct 15 17:27:20 2018 +0200

    [map] update the offline map cache to support the current styles
    
    - the old map cache cannot be loaded as it doesn't have the dark
      and light theme styles of neptune 3, hence, it needs to be
      updated
    
    Change-Id: Ib6640723d0090fc488e22c6808e47af9c7b6e40e
    Reviewed-by: Lukáš Tinkl <ltinkl@luxoft.com>

diff --git a/apps/com.pelagicore.map/maps/mapboxgl.db b/apps/com.pelagicore.map/maps/mapboxgl.db
index fc84344d..7291d76e 100644
--- a/apps/com.pelagicore.map/maps/mapboxgl.db
+++ b/apps/com.pelagicore.map/maps/mapboxgl.db
@@ -1,3 +1,3 @@
 version https://git-lfs.github.com/spec/v1
-oid sha256:09bd96ab35f610cdbdf84cc4b49a850c6af37d205c43c5e053a21ea6d37ccd6f
-size 103964672
+oid sha256:67d18923a064b1102451e864010b793a412b339d7d38682abd47a5641e4fa3ca
+size 52367360
```

Is there a way to correct this problem or ignore the old LFS references and push to my own remote?

Edit:
As I did not need the version history, I simply migrated a shallow copy of the latest state as desribed at [How to push a shallow clone to a new repo?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50992188/how-to-push-a-shallow-clone-to-a-new-repo/50996201#50996201)