# Can't push repository after shallow clone

Tags: git, github, azure-devops, git-clone, git-fetch

I am trying to import a repository (https://github.com/LibreOffice/core.git) into Azure Devops but can't due to the fact it has corrupted commits (too many < or wrong spaces etc far back in its history). This also prevents it being imported into Github.

A solution I have tried is to do a shallow clone (not include the old corrupted commits) to a local repo and then push that to Azure Devops but I get the error "shallow update not allowed" as explained in this previous thread [Remote rejected (shallow update not allowed) after changing Git remote URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28983842/remote-rejected-shallow-update-not-allowed-after-changing-git-remote-url)

All the solutions result in having to unshallow the repo first. I can't do that as doing that will include the corrupted commits. Is there no way of cloning and removing the corrupted commits?

Comment: you can just download the state you want and delete the `.git` folder and upload the files as there is no git history (you will lose all the git history, obv, but the upload will work)

Comment: Thanks - I assume I can't then push updates from the open source repo to my changes with this method? Or would there be a way to update new commits

Comment: And I assume I just clone then delete the init folder then run git init again?

Comment: i think you should be able to, git history doesnt have to be exactly the same to push updates to the origin

Comment: Thanks but how can I do that? I've deleted the git folder so it has not history or reference to the old repo. If I add it as origin and pull won't it pull all the history? How will it know what the new changes are without any history?

Answer (score 0):

You could try [git-cherry-pick](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick) to cherry-pick a range of commits and skip the corrupted commits:

```
$ git cherry-pick A^..B
```