# Github: how to fork after cloning?

Tags: git, github

I cloned a git repo to my local machine, played around with it a bit and found it cool.

Now I would like to keep the result as I modified it in my own github space. How can I proceed?

I suppose the regular way would have been to fork the repo on the first place to my space, clone it, modify and then push it to GitHub, but now I cloned the original's author repo, how can I commit that as a new thing in my personnal?

Comment: You might want to learn more about remotes: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Working-with-Remotes .

Answer (score 83, accepted):

First rename the old remote as upstream, in case you want to be able to keep in sync with the original repository.

```
git remote rename origin upstream
```

Then add your forked repository as origin:

```
git remote add origin https://github.com/<your-username>/<your-project>
```

Or if you're using ssh:

```
git remote add origin git@github.com:<your-username>/<your-project>.git
```

To push to your repository:

```
git push -u origin master
```

To pull from the base repository:

```
git pull upstream
```

I recommend you do all of your work in a separate branch, not the master branch. It will be easier to rebase to the `upstream/master` branch in case you want to make a pull request.

You don't really have to rename the `origin` to `upstream` - the remote names can be arbitrary, however I recommended you to do so to keep up with the [naming convention used by GitHub](https://help.github.com/articles/fork-a-repo/#keep-your-fork-synced).

Comment: Hi, I think made these steps and now when I hit `git status` I get notifications for `upstream` instead of origin. I want it to say that I'm in sync if I have synced with origin. Any advise?

Comment: Have you tried checking out your branch `git checkout <my_branch>` and typing: `git branch --set-upstream-to origin/my_branch`?

Comment: `git remote set-url origin <your repo>` if you want to overwrite origin :)

Comment: Thank you! I noticed that your acutally forced to rename the origin, otherwise you get`fatal: remote origin already exists`

Comment: Always wondered how I can easily keep my forked project in sync with the main repository. Definitely worth keeping this as part of the open source workflow!

Answer (score 3):

On the github webpage create a fork in the usual way. Then go to your repository and add a remote which points to your fork: `git remote add myfork git@github.com:you/your-fork.git`. This adds a remote called "myfork" which you can push to. You could also change the url of the "origin" fork; this will get you exactly the same state as if you had cloned from your fork to begin with: `git remote set-url origin git@github.com:you/your-fork.git`.

Comment: I did those steps from a powershell which I opened from Github Desktop by right mousing on my local repository. I then followed the first two steps. Renaming and adding (with the first suggestion, no SSH. Can I try doing again WITH SSH (git@github...) without any harm?  Is there a way to know if I should be working with SSH or not? 

Anyway, at the third step I get , after: git push -u origin master 
error: src refspec master does not match any. 
error: failed to push some refs to https://github.com/myname/myproj

What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to [TomasHubelbauer](https://gist.github.com/TomasHubelbauer) for these [instructions](https://gist.github.com/jagregory/710671?permalink_comment_id=4444019#gistcomment-4444019):

Install [Github CLI](https://github.com/cli/cli).

Set up [access](https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_auth_login) to your Github account using `gh auth login`.

Run [`gh repo fork`](https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_repo_fork) in the repository you cloned.

> Would you like to add a remote for the fork? Yes