# remote: Permission to NotMyRepo.git denied to Me. fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/NotMyRepo.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403

Tags: github, repository, push, commit, git-remote

I cloned a repo, and I wanted to add some functionality.

I could simply copy/paste on to my own project, but I wanted to use the "add personal" option instead, because the main code is not mine after all, so copying it with CTRL+C + CTRL+V would not be fair imo.

By "add personal" option I mean [$ git remote add personal http://github.com/YOU/YOUR_REPO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18200424/11214643)

I created the folder in my repo were the commit would end, and ever since (2 days now) I've been trying to commit the changes + the cloned code to that repo without success, and Ive tried every answer on SO (config username / email, ssh key pair creation, ssh agent, git bash commands, windows cmd, installing all github apps + bash, control panel, secret passphrase or whatever, etc... etc.. etc...), without any success, also half the solutions are now to no use since github now uses tokens to do anything and the ide (Android Studio) keeps asking me for tokens each try (my account is now filled with tokens for each attempt), the "complete" error is this:

remote: Permission to NotMyRepo.git denied to Me. fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/NotMyRepo.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403

I guess it would make sense that I need permission from the author, but ... I could simply copy paste so, if I was able to clone why am I not allowed to "add a new remote".

Answer (score 0):

So the "solution" was:

I copied all my changes into multiple notepads.

Then deleted the entire project from my pc(to prevent naming issues)

Then used the "fork" option (of the NotMyRepo.git) in the GitHub web app
[image]

Then cloned : `git -> clone...`.

Pasted the changes.

Finally I could commit.

Answer (score 0):

You have to search in window "**credential manager**" -> **window credentials** -> click to "**git:https://github.com**" and remove it