How can I clone a git repo, create my own repo from it and be able to access changes to the original I cloned?
I am very new to repositories so please be gentle.
I am using this repo to build a website https://github.com/Oak-Harbor-Kits/Starter-Kit-V4-Eleventy/tree/main
I have cloned it but when I try and push it to a repo I made I get an error saying "fatal error access denied"
I would like for my new repo to have the capability to pull any changes originating in the starter kit (don't know if this makes sense or would work considering it would probably re-write all of my changes to the html and css).
How should I go about this? Would something like this need to be forked (still working on understanding what this means) or is the solution simpler and I should just copy and paste the cloned repo into a new folder and commit that instead?
I have downloaded the zip file and attempted to commit from the modified zip but that gave me the error. I then copied the contents of the repo into a new folder and was able to successfully commit to my new repo from there, but am unsure if this is considered ok and if any future changes pushed to the original starter kit will be easily applied.

This question is similar to: Cloning a repo from someone else's Github and pushing it to a repo on my Github. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

First of all, you will need to fork the project. This essentially means you create a copy of the project which will show up on your own GitHub profile.
You will have access to your fork (copy) of the project, but will not the original project (as you already found out).
On your local machine (assuming that's where you want to make your changes) you can either clone your fork and be done with it, if you don't need any changes from the original project.
If you do need the changes from the original project, you will need to define 2 remotes; one for your fork (where you will push your changes) and one for the original (where you will fetch/pull changes and apply them to your project).

For the second option would that look like one of the top two answers in this thread just instead making a fork and cloning that? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18200248/cloning-a-repo-from-someone-elses-github-and-pushing-it-to-a-repo-on-my-github

@Dewbrew yes that looks right

Any project that you want to receive changes when the starter kit is updated must be a branch of the starter kit. I would create the started kit project and create a branch for starter kit updated and a branch for each of the projects you use the starter kit to create. When you commit a change from the starter kit update you would need to push them to any projects under the starter kit that you wanted to receive the update. Make sure that only the starter kit update branch updates the starter kit project.

Would you say that I should follow the steps here between the top two answers (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18200248/cloning-a-repo-from-someone-elses-github-and-pushing-it-to-a-repo-on-my-github) and then create branches for each of my projects as you've said?
